# Upgrade to angular 2 RC7 issue with routes

Tags: angular

I am trying to upgrade our app to angular 2 RC7 with router 3.0.0.rc-3 from RC5. 
But I get the following errors on the child routes files.

```
ERROR in [default]       C:/src/app/routes/childroute1/child-routes-one.routes.ts:31:8
Type '{ path: string; component: typeof childRouteOne; data: {    displayName: string; }; childre...' is not assignable to type 'Route[]'.
Type '{ path: string; component: typeof childRouteOne; data: { displayName: string; }; childre...' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
  Type '({ path: string; redirectTo: string; terminal: boolean; } | { path: string; component: typeof fea...' is not assignable to type 'Route[]'.
    Type '{ path: string; redirectTo: string; terminal: boolean; } | { path: string; component: typeof feas...' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
      Type '{ path: string; redirectTo: string; terminal: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
        Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'terminal' does not exist in type 'Route'.
```

Do I have to change (add or delete) anything in the child routes? Or is the problem with any of the dependencies?

When I tried with `@angular/router : 3.0.0.rc-2` and `rxjs: 5.0.0-beta.6` , I did not get an error.

child-routes-one.routes.ts

```
import {Routes, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
export const settingsRoute: Routes = [
{
path: 'ev/route-one/:Id/:usrId',
component: childRouteOne,
data: { displayName: 'Settings' },
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    terminal: true
  },
  { path: 'home', component: feature-home, data: { displayName: 'Home' } },
  { path: 'notes/notes-settings/:Id', component: notesSettings, data: { displayName: 'Notifications' } }

   ]
  }
];
```

@NgModule imports:

```
imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule, CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, routing, RouterModule.forChild(settingsRoute) ],
```

Comment: show routing code.

Comment: Please post more code. `@NgModule()`, routes, ...

Comment: **Angular 2 Final** was release almost a month ago. I'd strongly recommend upgrading.
Router guide: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Added routing code and NgModule in the original question

Comment: @AndreiZhytkevich I tried upgrading from RC5 directly to 2.0.0 , I still face the issue with the child routes mentioned in my original question

Comment: `terminal` is not a valid option anymore, try taking that out and see if it will build

Comment: @DaveV Perfect! That works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `terminal` property is no longer supported in the newer Routers.  Take that out and everything should build.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **terminal property** and try to implement what is shown here,

```
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  ...
]
```